# Rowsource not working via VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I can't get the RowSource property of a list box to update via VBA. From another thread, I found the syntax, so I think this is correct. But, despite not failing, it doesn't do anything to the RowSource property (it remains blank). Below:

frmAddIngredient is the user form.

lbxIngredient is a listbox control in that form.

UniqueIngredients is one of the sheets in the workbook.

NumberOfItems is 1 (in this case).

It doesn't give an error, but it doesn't change anything, either. The form itself is not active at this time. This code is supposed to set up the form for later showing.

```
frmAddIngredient.lbxIngredient.RowSource = Sheets("UniqueIngredients").Range("A1:A" & CStr(NumberOfItems)).Address
```

The most recent code is

```
        frmAddIngredient.lbxIngredient.RowSource = "=UniqueIngredients!A1:A1"
```

but, it still doesn't change anything in the actual form.

Also, can I add a new post, or do I have to continue editing this one and adding stuff?

Comment: You're giving it `$A$1:$A$42` for a value. How does it know what worksheet that's referring to? Did you try to `Set` it to the actual `Range` instead of assigning to a `Range.Address` string?

Comment: I don't understand your question. The worksheet is "UniqueIngredients". What I want to get populated is all the cells in column A. In my example, I only want cell A1.

Comment: Yes, and what do you think `Sheets("UniqueIngredients").Range("A1:A" & CStr(NumberOfItems)).Address` evaluates to?

Comment: Sorry, when I hit Enter to add a new line, it pushed out the comment. See the revised comment.

Comment: I'm not sure what .address does, but I presume it all evaluates to cell A1 in sheet UniqueIngredients.

Comment: Basically you're assigning to some address string, but that string doesn't include the sheet name, so it doesn't know what to do with that string, so nothing happens (would be nice if it blew up) - try assigning to the `Range` itself instead (with the `Set` keyword, since this is an object)

Comment: try with `"UniqueIngredients!A1:A1"` note, I've remove the second equal sign (=)

Comment: No, still no change without the equal sign inside the quotes.

Comment: Are you by chance hoping to see the rowsource show up in the listbox property window by setting it via code? like in this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fwa4C.png)

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want (as discussed in the comments on your question) is not possible. Setting something by code does not change it's property in the properties window and is only so until your project resets.

Consider a Userform with 2 buttons, with their original name and caption and then in a module paste these 2 subs.

```
Sub demo1()
    UserForm1.CommandButton1.Caption = "Demo 1"
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub

Sub demo2()
    UserForm1.CommandButton2.Caption = "Demo 2"
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

When you run the first Sub `demo1` Button 1's caption has changed but Button 2's caption has not.

[image]

Close the Userfom and now run `demo2`, you'll see that Button 1's caption is back to it's original hard set (properties window) name and that now Button 2 has a different name.

[image]